# removeClass for AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use `removeClass` for `AJAX` loaded DIVs?

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.message').each(function() {
        var message_id = $(this).data('id');
        if ($(this).hasClass('message-not-read')) {
            $.get('message-set-read.php?message-id=' + message_id, function(data) {
                if (data == 'is-set-read') {
                    $(this).removeClass('message-not-read'));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

DIVs with class `.message` and `.message-not-read` are loaded through another `$.load()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to store your `this` before you make your AJAX call, since it changes your context :

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.message').each(function() {
        var that = $(this); //Here
        var message_id = that.data('id');
        if (that.hasClass('message-not-read')) {
            $.get('message-set-read.php?message-id=' + message_id, function(data) {
                if (data == 'is-set-read') {
                    that.removeClass('message-not-read'));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the scope of `this` has changed inside the `$.get` handler, so it no longer refers to the current `.message` element in the iteration. You need to store that reference in a variable for use in the inner scope.

Also note that you can include the required class in the selector and remove the `if` condition, like this:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.message.message-not-read').each(function() {
    var $message = $(this);
    $.get('message-set-read.php?message-id=' + $message.data('id'), function(data) {
      $message.toggleClass('message-not-read', data !== 'is-set-read'));
    });
  });
}, 5000);
```

Also note that looping through all your messages and sending an AJAX request for each of them every 5 seconds is a really bad idea. It would make more sense to either invert the logic so that you make a single AJAX request which gets the state of all visible messages on the screen which you can then update, or better yet, use websockets if you need to keep the UI/server data in close synchronisation.

Comment: For the loop, it fires every 5 seconds but the AJAX request will be sent ONLY if the message has .message-not-read so ONLY for a new incoming message.